# How to set enum value in an interface?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use enum as the value in interface description. TypeScript understands the typing but fails to check an object:

```
enum Type {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
  C = 'C'
}

interface ABC {
  type: Type
}

interface A extends ABC {
  type: Type.A
}

const a: A = { type: 'a' }
// Type '{ type: "a"; }' is not assignable to type 'A'.
//   Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
//     Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'Type.A'.
```

Although, when I set an enum directly `const a : A = { type: Type.A }` or use a string as the value then it works as intended:

```
interface A {
  type: 'a'
}

const a: A = { type: 'a' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected and intended behavior. See [this ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17690) for the relevant discussion. The gist of it is, that you should not attempt to hardcode enum values, as enum values are specifically design to hide away the underlying constant.

The correct way to do this in case you don't need to assign string literal but can use the enum would be:

```
   enum Type {
      A = 'a',
        B = 'b',
          C = 'C'
   }

   interface ABC {
         type: Type
   }

   interface A extends ABC {
         type: Type.A
   }

   const a: A = { type: Type.A }
```

There is always the option to use typecasts `let a: A = {type: "a" as Type.A};` but you will not get typesafety if you do this. I'd stick to the first pattern and if you have any user supplied values you would need to check the value anyways (I'e validate if it is indeed 'a') since typechecking is compile time only.

```
let a: A;
if (userValue === Type.A) {
      a = { type: userValue };
}
```